# ¿Hay una traducción adecuada de "venom"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, animales

[***Venom***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom) es

> A form of toxin secreted by an animal for the purpose of causing harm to another.

Por otro lado, en la página de Wikipedia correspondiente a [***Poison***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison) se recoge:

> The fields of medicine (particularly veterinary) and zoology often distinguish a poison from a toxin, and from a venom. Toxins are poisons produced by organisms in nature, and venoms are toxins injected by a bite or sting (this is exclusive to animals). The difference between venom and other poisons is the delivery method.

Entiendo, por tanto, que mientras que ***poison*** es la palabra genérica correspondiente a [**veneno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bWvfiiZ)

> Sustancia que, introducida en un ser vivo, es capaz de producir graves alteraciones funcionales e incluso la muerte.

***venom*** hace referencia exclusivamente al veneno **que se inyecta por picadura o mordedura de un animal**.

Todas los diccionarios que he consultado traducen ***venom*** simplemente como "**veneno**". ¿Hay alguna palabra que recoja mejor el matiz específico de "*venom*" frente a "*poison*"?

Comment: Curiosamente, "venom" tiene el mismo origen latino que "veneno", mientras que "poison" tiene el mismo origen que "poción". Yo diría que "venom" sería un "veneno inyectado".

Comment: A quick search n "culebras venenosas" shows that it refers to poisonous snakes,  aka venomous snakes.  This may not even  need a different word.

Comment: Right.  And you can see that even Wikipedia has a problem when you go to the English article on "venom", and then click on the Español link over on the left menu.  You get the Spanish article for "Animales venenosos", which isn't the same article!

Comment: En el enlace siguiente, hay una descripción dle veneno de sapos.  Se utiliza la palabra veneno y la palabra toxina como si fueran sin[onimos. http://www.venfido.com.mx/enfermedad.php?n=intoxicacion-por-veneno-de-sapo-en-perros

Answer (score 4):

In Spanish [**veneno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bWvfiiZ) is a translation of both **venom** and **poison**. The word [**ponzoña**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Texgwl3) is equivalent to both as well. The use could be regional but in Mexico, **ponzoña** is only used meaning **venom** (injected by an animal.) An animal that injects venom is regarded as **animal ponzoñoso**.

If toxins are secreted through the skin or affect after ingestion, they are called [**toxinas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aB74oqG).

All types of living agents that produce toxins to defend themselves are regarded as **venenoso** (i.e. **plantas venenosas**, **animales venenosos**.)

If one gets poisoned after ingesting them they can also be regarded as [**tóxicos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aAx6mN5). But any chemical compound also can be **tóxico** regardless of having a biologic origin or not.

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser que no hay una traducción exacta. El idioma español llega hasta la palabra [toxina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aB74oqG) como "veneno producido por organismos vivos". Sin embargo, la distinción entre una toxina cualquiera y una toxina inyectada ya no existe en nuestro idioma. El problema añadido es que el término "venom" tiene el mismo origen latino que "veneno", y por tanto nos resulta sencillo quedarnos con esta palabra para describir cualquier tipo de veneno, sea cual sea su método de introducirse en el organismo.

De hecho, según el [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/) la traducción oficial de "venom" es "veneno". Por tanto veo complicado encontrar una traducción mejor.

Si te resulta complicado traducir frases como:

> *Are there any animals that are both poisonous and venomous?*

como la de la pregunta que enlazas, yo lo haría así:

> ¿Existen animales que produzcan toxinas tanto inyectables como secretables o ingeribles?

Es decir, haría hincapié en el método de producción (o expulsión) de dicha toxina o veneno. Tu otro ejemplo,

> *Is poison venomous and is venom poisonous?*

lo traduciría así una vez leído el contenido de la pregunta:

> ¿Surten efecto los venenos ingeribles si se inyectan? ¿Y los inyectables si se ingieren?